# Stone age expansion How trading works question

Tags: expansions, stone-age

Just played our first game of Stone Age with the expansion and we have a question.

All the examples show a single use of the trading ability.  Does that mean that you are limited to a single trade per turn or can you do multiples but only towards a single card/hut?

So, can you trade 14 wood for 7 gold on a 1-7 hut using the lowest level of trade?  You would then be able to score 7*6 (42) points off of 14 wood.

Please help me understand the limits of trading in the Stone Age Expansion.

Lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the rules: http://www.zmangames.com/uploads/4/7/1/7/47170931/en-stone-age-ext_rules.pdf

> A player may:
>
> - Trade only once his marker has moved off of space 0 of the    merchant track.
> - Only trade in order to acquire a Civilization card or Building    tile.
> - Trade the resources and jewelry of their choice.
> - Improve his trading ability by advancing on the merchant track,    allowing for  2 to 1 ,  1 to 1 , and even  1 to 2  trades.
> - Trade    even if he did not place two figures at the merchant this round.
> - Important: A player may only trade once per round.

So you can only make one trade per round